# Stripe Connect - shared customer , cant charge

Tags: node.js, stripe-connect

Hi I am trying to implement stripe connect where the platform takes an application fee but the connected user gets majority of charge.

Following this as my guide
https://stripe.com/docs/connect/shared-customers

I have this as my code. The user is saved w/ default credit card source in another view.

```
    Parse.Cloud.define("chargeCard", function(req, res){
      stripe.tokens.create({
        customer: req.params.customer,
      }, {
        stripe_account: req.params.stripeAccount,
      }).then((token) => {
        console.log("successfully created token");
        stripe.charges.create({
          amount: req.params.amount,
          currency: req.params.currency,
          source: token.id,
          application_fee: req.params.fee,
        }, {
          stripe_account: req.params.stripeAccount,
        }).then((charge) => {
          console.log("successfully charged card");
          res.success(charge);
        }).catch((error) => {
          console.log(error);
          res.error(error.message);
        });
      }).catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
        res.error(error.message);
      });
    });
```

But receive the error:

"You provided a customer without specifying a source. The default source of the customer is a source and cannot be shared from existing customer".

Im not able to specify its default source in the create token body. any help?

Answer (score 0):

This issue was with the users source. Although the user had a credit card source it is not "shareable" (as the error kinda states) , you need to create a shared source when using stripe-connect.

https://stripe.com/docs/sources/connect#creating-direct-charges

You want to use this instead of the above tokens.create for direct charges in stripe-connect.

```
stripe.sources.create({
  customer: "cus_AFGbOSiITuJVDs",
  usage: "reusable",
  original_source: "src_19YP2AAHEMiOZZp1Di4rt1K6",
}, {
  stripe_account: "{CONNECTED_STRIPE_ACCOUNT_ID}",
}).then(function(token) {
  // asynchronously called
});
```

FYI: I do not save or attach this new source, kept the primary one and the regenerate a new token for each purchase since my application is 1 to many sellers.